# .net forms authentication question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-authentication

i'm working on a custom login page in mvc.net. I check logins like so:

```
public bool Login(string login, string password, bool persistent)
{
  var loginEntity = this.AdminRepository.GetLogin(login, password);
  if (loginEntity != null)
  {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login, persistent);

    HttpContext.Current.Session["AdminId"] = loginEntity.AdminId;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["AdminUsername"] = loginEntity.Username;

  return true;
  }
```

then i decorate any controller that needs admin access with a filter attribute:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

  // check if session is supported
  if (ctx.Session != null)
  {
    var redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();

    // check if a new session id was generated
    if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
    {
        // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
        // have timed out
        string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
        if (((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)) || null == sessionCookie)
        {
          redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
          redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", "Admin");
          redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "LogOn");
          redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");

          filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
        }
      } else if (SessionContext.AdminId == null) {
        redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", "Admin");
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "LogOn");
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
      }
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

I see that after log in I have two cookies:

1. ASPXAUTH (with expiration date set
   to "At end of session" (when
   persists is false) OR (30 min from
   now (when persists is set to true)
2. and ASP.NET_SessionId which
   expiration time is always "At end of
   session"

Question:
The problem is that even though i set TRUE to "persists" option (which will set ASPXAUTH  expiration time 30 min from now -which is good) my Session["AdminId"] is always null after i close and reopen the browser. How do i make sure my Sessions (Session["AdminId"] and Session["AdminUsername"]) are pulled in from the cookie when I initially do set "persists" to true and close then re-open the browswer window.
thanks

Comment: The persistent parameter works by setting the Expires property of the cookie if set to true. What have you set Expires to in your web.config. Have you tried inspecting the content of cookie with ie. Fiddler to see if Expires is set or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here:[Is it possible to use .ASPXAUTH for my own logging system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122831/is-it-possible-to-use-aspxauth-for-my-own-logging-system)

and this is what i did:

```
    public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controller action filter is used to check whether the session is still active. If the session has expired filter redirects to the login screen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {
            // check if a new session id was generated
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                var identity = ctx.User.Identity;

                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if (((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)) || null == sessionCookie)
                {
                    var redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", string.Empty);
                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "LogOn");
                    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "User");

                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
                }

                // Authenticated user, load session info
                else if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var loginRepository = new LoginRepository(InversionOfControl.Container.Resolve<IDbContext>());
                    IAuthenticationService authenticationService = new AuthenticationService(loginRepository);
                    authenticationService.SetLoginSession(identity.Name);
                }
            }
            else if (SessionContext.LoginId == null)
            {
                var redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", string.Empty);
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "LogOn");
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "User");

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cookie with an expiry time gets written to disk. The user will therefore still be logged in next time they open a browser, provided that the cookie has not expired.

A session cookie is stored only in memory, and is lost as soon as the browser is closed.

A session cookie is a cookie without an expiry date.

Comment: my ASP.NET_SessionId cookie does not have expiration date even though i set persists to true. ?

Comment: If you do not set it, the default is 30 mins

Comment: yes, that works but how do i pull my session stuff from the cookie. please see edited question above. thanks